# Dynamic SQL syntax using EXECUTE IMMEDIATE

Tags: oracle, dynamic-sql, ora-00904, execute-immediate

Dynamic SQL update statement as below:

`EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE '||l_prefix||'CRS_CUSTOMERS SET CUSTOMER_SOURCE_REF_ID = '||i.CUSTOMER_REF_ID||' WHERE CUSTOMER_ID = '||i.CUSTOMER_ID;`

`l_prefix` is the parameter hold the prefix of table name, the value assigned is T_
`i.CUSTOMER_REF_ID` and `i.CUSTOMER_ID` are the fields fetched from cursor.

The dynamic statement encounter error `ORA-00904: invalid identifier` when data fetched.

When rewrite it in static way, the query is working fine:

`UPDATE T_CRS_CUSTOMERS SET CUSTOMER_SOURCE_REF_ID = i.CUSTOMER_REF_ID WHERE
CUSTOMER_ID = i.CUSTOMER_ID;`

I know it must be something wrong on the concatenation of dynamic SQL, just couldn't pinpoint any as the compilation is fine.

Comment: put a `dbms_output.put_line`  in place of `execute immediate`, with parentheses and see the output query, does it match with the static update statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**WARNING**: Dynamic SQL like this is susceptible to SQL Injection attacks.  Wherever possible rewrite your dynamic SQL to use bind variables instead.

Instead of constructing your dynamic SQL like this:

```
L_SQL := 'UPDATE '||l_prefix||'CRS_CUSTOMERS SET CUSTOMER_SOURCE_REF_ID = '||i.CUSTOMER_REF_ID||' WHERE CUSTOMER_ID = '||i.CUSTOMER_ID;
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE L_SQL;
```

Use this:

```
L_SQL := 'UPDATE '||l_prefix||'CRS_CUSTOMERS SET CUSTOMER_SOURCE_REF_ID = :REF_ID WHERE CUSTOMER_ID = :CUST_ID';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE L_SQL USING i.CUSTOMER_REF_ID, i.CUSTOMER_ID;
```

This is still subject to SQL injection at the `l_prefix`, but if you control that value programatically it may be OK.  Also splitting the construction of the SQL and execution of the SQL into two steps allows you to more easily replace the `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` with `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQL);` to check your query for syntax errors.  You can also want to `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` your parameters `i.CUSTOMER_REF_ID` and `i.CUSTOMER_ID` to check their values.

Comment: if i have more than one `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` assign to `L_SQL` why that's only the first statement get executed? Should i assign to different variable?

Comment: I got it..it require a different set bind variables to reference each `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` statement